# Can bacteria be considered carnivores?

Tags: bacteriology, ecology

Ok carnivores are "animals that eat other animals," so what are bacteria that eat animals? Or are they just not important

Comment: I think it's more that bacteria are a special case. As they don't directly *consume* anything, taking the so-called "flesh eating bacteria that cause necrotizing faciitis as a good example: they simple release compounds or toxins that break down the surrounding matrix or tissues and absorb the products. In that sense you could call them saprophytes, saprovores or saprophages: organisms that consume decaying organic matter.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! "carnivores are animals that eat other animals" well, its a bit different. [A carnivore is an organism that derives its energy and nutrient requirements from a diet consisting mainly or exclusively of animal tissue, whether through predation or scavenging.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnivore) Bacteria ain't that choosy, are they?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about biology. It is an attempt to provoke a pointless discussion of semantics.

Comment: @David I disagree; understanding how technical words are defined in a scientific field and why those definitions were chosen is about as pointful as semantic discussions can get. It looks to me like there's the potential for good and informative answers there is what i'm saying. Unless "attempt to provoke a pointless discussion" is an informed statement about the OP's intentions (i.e. they're an outright troll) of course.

Comment: @RozennKeribin — I call them as I see them. You are entitled to your opinion, but I do recommend that you reread the tour to this site and especially https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask, and then consider whether questions are or are not in the spirit of and useful to this site.